# Safari's "Quick Website Seach" Address Bar Feature Redirects Google to Ask Different

Tags: safari, search-engine

My default search engine in Safari is Bing (Amazon Gift cards FTW!).

I usually search Google by starting to type "`goo`" and hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> to to autocomplete, which enters search engine mode.

However, Google searches always come here. I removed `apple.stackexchange.com` from **Manage Websites** in Safari Search preferences:
[image: Safari > Preferences > Search]
But every time I visit the site it is automatically readded.

I don't mind it being there, but why are Google searches directing here?

[image: safari quick search selects ask different instead of google]

Comment: Could you turn off Pre-load top hit, disable all extensions. restart Safari   and then try it ?

Comment: Yes, and strangely, even when `apple.stackechange.com` is not in the list it still comes here.

Comment: I won't recommend removing the site from history, however, you can try removing it from "Manage Website data" under privacy and then use cmd + Shift + E  or empty cache under Develop menu

Comment: @ankii Empty Cache doesn't give any sort of feedback. But I tried your suggestions. EditL: And they worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://shouldiblamecaching.com

I won't recommend removing the site from history, however, you can try removing it from "Manage Website data" under Safari privacy preferences and then use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd> or Empty Cache under Develop menu.

Comment: Emptying the cache was [is] the [recurring] solution for me.

Comment: Can you run a Malwarebytes scan ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376918/yahoo-taking-over-my-google-search/376920#376920

Comment: Yes, I will if the problem returns. It's gone away for now though!