# Yahoo taking over my google search

Tags: macbook-pro

My default search engine is google, but when i search it goes to yahoo. I tried the extensions solutions but i don't have any extensions. what should I do?

send help.

Comment: Could you please show us a screenshot of the browser window?

Comment: What version of macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some malware on your Mac. Download MalwareBytes for Mac and scan your system, and also make sure to delete any "threats" that it finds.